# Backbone js .listenTo vs .on

Tags: backbone.js

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the following 2 lines of code? I don't understand why there are 2 different ways to do the same thing.

```
this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'change:completed', this.filterOne);
app.Todos.on('change:completed', this.filterOne);
```

Also when using .on, how do I determine is the default context?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`listenTo` is the newer and better option because these listeners will be automatically removed for you during `stopListening` which is called when a view gets removed (via `remove()`). Prior to `listenTo` there was a really insidious problem with phantom views hanging around forever (leaking memory and causing misbehavior) because view methods were referenced as event listeners on models even though the view instances themselves were long gone and no longer in the DOM.

If you want to read the back story for `listenTo`, search the backbone github repository for `listenTo` and read through some of the longer issue discussions.

As to the default context, several things can end up bound to `this`:

- if you do the binding via `this.listenTo`, it will always be the view instance (pointed out by Wim Leers in the comments)
- without `this.listenTo`, the story gets complicated

  - For misc events, it will be the global object (best to avoid this)
  - for DOM events, it will be the source element just like in regular DOM event binding
  - If you provide an explicit context (the 3rd argument to `foo.on`), backbone will use that (thus this is a more robust approach)
  - If you use the ECMA standard `function () {//your event handler}.bind(this)`, you can also manually control the context (also recommended)
  - As @mu pointed out, `_.bind` or `$.proxy` are available alternatives to ECMA `function.bind`
  - For backbone views, doing `this.bindAll('onClick', ...)` will ensure the view instance is the `this` context when any view methods are used as event handlers
- any events wired up by using the view's standard `events` property will get bound for you automatically to the view instance by backbone (this is belt & suspenders with `bindAll`)

So to summarize into some guidelines:

- use the `events` property whenever possible as it is concise and correct
- use `this.listenTo` for all bindings to models and collections
- any additional bindings remember to bind the context reliably using your preferred method. I usually use ECMA `Function.bind` because hey, standards, but there are several good options here.

Comment: There's also [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) if you don't want to (or can't) use ECMA's `bind`.

Comment: I came across `jasmine-headless-webkit` apparently complaining about ECMA's `bind`, with "undefined is not a function", though the jasmine suite passed in the browser. I switched to using Underscore's `bindAll`.

Comment: Note that you *cannot* set an explicit context when using `listenTo`; it's always the object that `listenTo` is a method on. There is no fourth argument.

Comment: If we need to set a specific context, can you give an example of an alternative?

Comment: @NickBarrett `app.Todos.on('change:completed', this.filterOne.bind(<specific_context>));` or `this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'change:completed', this.filterOne.bind(<specific_context>));`

Answer (score 0):

With `listenTo`, the object whose events you want to listen to is passed as the first argument. In the case of `on`, it is actually a method on that object.

The advantages of `listenTo` over `on` are:

- The listener keeps track of all the event handlers, making it easier to remove them all at once when needed.
- The callback’s context is always set to the listener itself.