# Backbone 'this' context passing to render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some reason, I can't get `this` to correctly be passed to the callback to render the view. I've tried _.bind and _.bindAll methods, but no matter which way I use to pass context, I always end up with a different `this` in *render* than I had in *initialize*

Any help is appreciated

```
  Navigation.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Navigation.Model,
    comparator : function(item) {
      return item.get("orderId");
    }
  });

  Menu = new Navigation.Collection();

  Navigation.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : 'nav',
    tagName : "div",
    className : "navigation",
    collection : Menu,
    initialize : function(e) {
      console.log(this);
      this.template = "navigation/list";
      this.settings = Settings;

      this.collection.on("add", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      console.log(this);

      var renderedContent = this.template(this.collection.toJSON());
      console.log(renderedContent);

      return this;
    },
```

Example with bind:

```
initialize : function(e) {
  this.collection.on("add", _.bind(this.render, this));
}
```

Example with bindAll:

```
initialize : function(e) {
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
  this.collection.on("add", this.render);
}
```

### Console output

First print:

```
child {cid: "view2", options: Object, views: Object, __manager__: Object, _removeViews: function…}
```

Second print:

```
Object {resolve: function, resolveWith: function, reject: function, rejectWith: function, notify: function…}
```

EDIT: Adding where 'render' is called. This is immediately after Navigation.View.List(seen above) is defined in the code.

```
Navigation.registerModule = function(data) {
  _.extend(data, {
    id : Math.random()
  });
  Menu.add(new Navigation.Model(data));
  Navigation.LayoutManager.removeView(true);
  Navigation.cachedRendering = null;
};
Navigation.View = new Navigation.Views.List();

Navigation.LayoutManager = new Backbone.Layout({
  views : {
    nav : Navigation.View
  }
});

Navigation.LayoutManager.$el.appendTo("nav");

Navigation.LayoutManager.render();

return Navigation;
```

EDIT: In case anyone else stumbles across the same thing, the solution is to use `beforeRender` and `afterRender`. The confusion happened because I was upgrading dependencies and the old version of *backbone.layoutmanager* did not have these two helpers, and `render()` was used instead - with a `manage` parameter to access the `after` state.

Comment: Can you post examples of how you tried to use `bind` and `bindAll`?  If used properly either one should absolutely be able to solve your issue.

Comment: `this.collection.on("add", _.bind(this.render, this));` and `_.bindAll(this, "render");` with `this.collection.on("add", this.render)`

Comment: So what is this in intialise and what is it in render?

Comment: see the edited original post. render remains the same throughout

Comment: @tsjnsn the `this` are different, but what are they? Please provide the `console.log` output for both.

Comment: added the output above.

Comment: Huh, it does seem like you are using bind correctly, yet somehow the `this` in your second console.log appears to be the return value of a `$.ajax` call.  This leads me to wonder something: why does your initialize method have an `e` argument?  Normally it would take an options argument ... are you using the view class directly as an event handler or something?  Could you please include the code for where you instantiate Navigation.Views.List?

Comment: Actually, could you include the code where the `render` method is being invoked too?

Comment: @tsjnsn It looks like your second this is a jQuery promise object: http://api.jquery.com/promise/ . Your trigger is likely fired from a jQuery call and hijacks the `this` keyword. This happens somewhere else in your code. Here is a Fiddle that shows that your code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/iamor/zNDDM/

Comment: @machineghost added the code that calls render().

Comment: @mor Good to know. Can you write an example that shows how hijacking 'this' occurs? I am not too familiar with that.

Comment: What's a `Backbone.Layout`?  This is clearly coming from some sort of 3rd party library, and that library is very likely the true source of your problem.

Comment: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager

Comment: @tsjnsn Looks like Backbone.Layout calls `render` in a particular way: it is asynchronous, hence the `$.promise` for `this` value. Have a look at this documentation: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Configuration#rendertemplate-context . Also, according to this line of code: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L378 it is possible to access the view's `this` by using something like `var self = this.view`.

Comment: @mor this.view is undefined. Also, the point where it calls the render method that I defined is here: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view render is getting called by this line of code:

https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L472:

```
  // Render the View into the el property.
  if (contents) {
    rendered = options.render.call(renderAsync, contents, context);
  }
```

The problem is that `options.render.call(renderAsync, contents, context);` binds the `this` keyword with `renderAsync` which is a promise.

I am not familiar with Backbone Layout Manager, but it looks like the original context is passed along as the second argument to the `render` method. You can then use it with slight modifications to your render method.

```
render: function( contents, context ) {
      var self = context ? context : this;    
      var renderedContent = this.template(self.collection.toJSON());    
      return this;
    },
```

Comment: `context` turns out to be something completely different. If I change L472 to `rendered = options.render.call(renderAsync, contents, root);`, then it gives me the context that you would expect.

Comment: @tsjnsn I must say that I don't really know why and how Backbone Layoutmanager works but it looks like it does some *black magic* and tries to automate some stuff for you. Clearly, `render` was not meant to be used the way you do. Anyhow, you might want to log the values of the `contents` and `context` variables to look if you can access the `root` object. If you are going to make the `this` context right by modifying L472, you could just change it to: `options.render.call(root, contents, context);` The first argument of `function.call` is going to be the `this` keyword.

Comment: I will try that. My original questions is answered, now I have many more :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
```

ListenTo was added in 0.9.x and is recommended because "... make it easier to create Views that have all of their observers unbound when you want to remove the view.", quoted from the backbone docs. Here's a good answer that goes into detail about context too which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824080/486434

Comment: I've tried this too. It produces the same results as the other methods.