# Model shows as undefined when render is called at event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, models

I have a view with the following `initialize` method:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.model.on("all", this.render)
},
```

And in the render method I access the model's content using:

```
var contents = this.model.attributes.content;
```

The `content` property of the model is an array.
So when I add something to the array using `model.set()` through the console, the render method is called, but I get the following error :`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined(…)`.
But after adding if I call `view.render()` manually, it renders the model nicely.
Again if I add anything, it throws the same error.
Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be the **context** ( the value of `this` ) in which the `render` is executed - due to the event trigger.

If you would put a debugger and examine the value of `this` inside the `render` which gets executed by the model change, it would not be holding the reference of `view`.

You can get this fixed by passing a third parameter to the `on` as specified in [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on):

```
this.model.on( 'all', this.render, this );
```

The third parameter is the **context** in which the `render` would be executed. Meaning, whatever you pass as the third parameter, would be the value of `this` inside the `render` function.

It's better to use `listenTo` instead of `on` as it cleans up the events in a better way than `on` does. You can read nice explanation for the same thing here at stackoverflow question [Backbone js .listenTo vs .on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16823746/983648).

So the initialize would be written as:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo( this.model, 'all', this.render );
}
```

And also, I would recommend to use the `get` method available in `model` to access it's attribute, hence instead of accessing `content` by `this.model.attributes.content` use `this.model.get( 'content' )`.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

since you are listening using `this.model.on("all", this.render)` 
your render function will be getting the model as the context i.e. when the callback is called 'this' will refer to the model. Try using 
`this.listenTo(this.model, "all", this.render)`. This way you can set the context.