# BackboneJS Radio channel triggers events more than once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am building a Backbone.js application, I use BackboneJS Radio for messaging.

First I created a channel:

```
App.actionsChannel = Backbone.Radio.channel('actions');
```

And when I click an action button, let's say 'next' action button:

```
App.actionsChannel.trigger('action:triggered', 'next');
```

And I handle the action:

```
App.actionsChannel.on('action:triggered', function(actionName){
  //do some ajax requests
});
```

The problem is, when I click the next button for the first time, it triggers the `next` action one time, and the second time, it triggers twice, the third time it triggers 4 times, and so on...

Every time I trigger the next action, it fires many times, not once. And when I checked the `actionsChannel._events`, I found it contains all the actions I triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the registering `on` is done multiple times, somewhere not shown in your question, and it should only be done once.

## ✘ Don't do this

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click": "onClick"
    },

    onClick: function(e) {
        App.actionsChannel.on('action:triggered', function(actionName) {
            //do some ajax requests
        });
    }
});
```

## ✔ Do this

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click": "onClick"
    },

    initialize: function(){
        App.actionsChannel.on('action:triggered', this.onActionTriggered);
    },

    onClick: function(e) {
        // or if you must register it here for example.
        // First make sure it's unregistered.
        App.actionsChannel.off('action:triggered', this.onActionTriggered);
        App.actionsChannel.on('action:triggered', this.onActionTriggered);
    },

    onActionTriggered: function(actionName) {
        //do some ajax requests
    },
});
```

Using the `on` function multiple times just adds another listener to the list. So, when triggered, the callback is called as much times as it was registered.

## The best

It is recommended to use `listenTo` instead of `on` whenever possible to avoid memory leaks.

[Backbone.js `on` vs `listenTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on)

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click": "onClick"
    },

    initialize: function(){
        // this will be removed automatically when the view is `remove`d,
        // avoiding memory leaks.
        this.listenTo(App.actionsChannel, 'action:triggered', this.onActionTriggered);
    },

    onClick: function(e) {

    },

    onActionTriggered: function(actionName) {
        //do some ajax requests
    },
});
```

The code snippets above are just examples of how to listen to an event. Use `trigger` where you need it and where it make sense.

Comment: I only use the `on` function in one place. I have two views, one triggers the event, and other catches it on the initialize

Comment: I think the issue is that I have zombie views, when the route changes, a new view created before the current view that catches the event is destroyed

Comment: Favor `listenTo` over `on` for that reason.

Comment: @kdureidy even if you have the `on` on one place, my answer is still on point, it's called more than once. A zombie view is just a case where something might be called more than expected.

Comment: I will try your solution, but where in your code do you use `trigger`?

Comment: I don't think listenTo will help in this case, since the action name may always be the same `next`

Comment: @kdureidy `listenTo` removes listener of a view (or object) when it's destroyed, or when you call `this.stopListening()`. On the other hand, each call to `on` needs to be individually removed with `off` if you don't want to break the "wiring" and avoid memory leaks.