# How does this Backbone todo app render all the elements to the page?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I type in `open <this_filename.html>` in my terminal, it opens the page with the `todolist` model list already rendered on the page. How?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>To-do App in Backbone.js</title>

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!--    CSS    -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Hides bullet points from todo list */
    #todoapp ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- Your HTML -->
  <!-- ========= -->

  <section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <input id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" autofocus>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
      <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
    </section>
  </section>
  <div>
    <p>Find the tutorial and code in <a href="http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/11/backbone-dot-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started/">here</a></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Templates -->
  <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label><%- title %></label>
    </div>
  </script>

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- Libraries -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- =============== -->
  <!-- Javascript code -->
  <!-- =============== -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    var app = {}; // create namespace for our app

    //--------------
    // Models
    //--------------
    app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
      }
    });

    //--------------
    // Collections
    //--------------
    app.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: app.Todo,
      localStorage: new Store("backbone-todo")
    });

    // instance of the Collection
    app.todoList = new app.TodoList();

    //--------------
    // Views
    //--------------

    // renders individual todo items list (li)
    app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'li',
      template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
      render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this; // enable chained calls
      }
    });

    // renders the full list of todo items calling TodoView for each one.
    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#todoapp',
      initialize: function () {
        this.input = this.$('#new-todo');
        app.todoList.on('add', this.addAll, this);
        app.todoList.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        app.todoList.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
      },
      events: {
        'keypress #new-todo': 'createTodoOnEnter'
      },
      createTodoOnEnter: function(e){
        if ( e.which !== 13 || !this.input.val().trim() ) { // ENTER_KEY = 13
          return;
        }
        app.todoList.create(this.newAttributes());
        this.input.val(''); // clean input box
      },
      addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new app.TodoView({model: todo});
        $('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
      },
      addAll: function(){
        this.$('#todo-list').html(''); // clean the todo list
        app.todoList.each(this.addOne, this);
      },
      newAttributes: function(){
        return {
          title: this.input.val().trim(),
          completed: false
        }
      }
    });

    //--------------
    // Initializers
    //--------------

    app.appView = new app.AppView();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

At the bottom of the code, this line: `app.appView = new app.AppView();` instantiates the `AppView`. Is the `reset` function automatically called?

I think I understand how the `addAll` and `addOne` methods are defined, but I'm wondering what calls them in the first place? How is the `todoList` rendered on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new app.AppView();
```

This calls the `initialize` function of `app.AppView`.

```
initialize: function () {
    // this is where addAll is called
    app.todoList.on('add', this.addAll, this);
    app.todoList.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    app.todoList.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
},
```

Listeners are bound to the `add` and `reset` events of the collection `app.todoList` and uses `this.addAll` as a callback.

When calling `.fetch()` on the collection, it adds new models to it, triggering the `add` event, which then triggers the callback `this.addAll`.

In my opinion though, with the newest Backbone version, it should use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) which is a better version of `on`:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(app.todoList, {
        'add': this.addOne, // on the add event, only use addOne
        'reset': this.addAll // on collection reset, re-render everything
    });
    app.todoList.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
},
```

[`listenTo` vs `on`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on)

Comment: you're the best. Thanks a lot!