# Function _.bind() won't bind an object

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, underscore.js, sugarcrm

I have a view class extending SugarCRM `CreateView` and I want `this` to be `this.model` in function `checkMonths` when the field `starting_months_c` is changed, so I could type `this.get()` instead of `this.model.get()`.

```
/**
 * @class View.Views.Base.DoVPCreateView
 * @alias SUGAR.App.view.views.DoVPCreateView
 * @extends View.Views.Base.CreateView
 */
({
    extendsFrom: 'CreateView',
    initialize: function(options) {
        this._super('initialize', arguments);
        // ....
        this.model.on('change:starting_month_c', _.bind(this.checkMonths, this.model));
        // ....
    },
    checkMonths: function() {
        if (this.get('starting_month') == 12) {
            // ....
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this construct does not work. I wonder, maybe it is because the `.on()` function somehow sets the context itself?

I found out in the doc, that you can pass the context to the function as third parameter

```
object.on(event, callback, [context])
```

I tried this but the result is still the same - the view is `this`, not the `model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick fix

Give the context directly to `.on`:

```
this.model.on('change:starting_month_c', this.checkMonths, this.model);
```

But doing this is only a misleading fix. The view's functions should all have `this` being the view instance and not other arbitrary objects.

```js
// a simple example view
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("View init, month:", this.model.get('month'));
    
    // bind the context
    this.model.listenTo(this.model, "change:month", this.checkMonth);
  },
  // the callback
  checkMonth: function() {
    // here, `this` is the model which you should NOT do.
    // but for demonstration purpose, you can use `this.get` directly.
    console.log("checkMonth:", this.get('month'));
  },
});

// sample for the demo
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    month: 2 // dummy value
  }),
  view = new View({
    model: model
  });

console.log("change month");
model.set({
  month: 3 // set to trigger the callback
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

## Real fix

If you always want to trigger a check "months" callback whenever `starting_month_c` changes in any instance of this model, you could move that into the model class itself.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // favor listenTo over `on` or `bind`
        this.listenTo(this, 'change:starting_month_c', this.checkMonths);
    },
    checkMonths: function(model, value, options) {
        if (this.get('starting_month') === 12) {
            // whatever you want
        }
    }
});
```

If it's only for this specific view, **use `this.model.get` in the callback as it should be**. This is not a problem, it's the standard way of doing it.

More info on why to [favor `listenTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on).

Comment: The point is, that I want to have some validations only when I create the model. But you are rignt - not having this as the class in class function is kinda messy, I can see it now... I'll normally use this.model.get() :) However (now purely for educational purposes) as I wrote in my edit, I tried to pass the model as the context, and the result still did not come

Comment: @Charlestone as an educational example, I added a stack snippet demonstrating it works as expected. So if it doesn't work from your side, something else is changing the context of pre-binding every instance function manually somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the context is more this than this.model:

```
.bind(this.checkMonths, this)
```

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/User_Interface/Views/Adding_Field_Validation_to_the_Record_View/index.html