# How to avoid a memory leak when instantiating child views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
myView =  Backbone.View.extend({
    //event binding etc etc

    render: function() {
        //render some DOM
    }
})

anotherView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .selector doThis'
    },

    createNewView: function() {
        var view = new myView();
    }
})
```

`createNewView` may be called multiple times. My understanding is that the variable `view` will not necessarily be removed by JavaScript's built-in garbage collection because it references objects/code which still exists when the `createNewView` function completes.

Is this correct? How to deal with this?

My current approach is to initialise `myView` once at the level of my app:

```
myApp.view = new myView()
```

Then in `createNewView` I just call render on this:

```
myApp.view.render()
```

Essentially, I only ever have one of them and I re-use it.

An alternative approach is to track the creation of sub views in an array and then I call `.remove()` on each one in turn when I know they are no longer needed.

Am I on the right track?

It occurs to me that the second approach is better because if `myView` created bound callbacks on other objects with `listenTo`, these would not be removed simply by re-assigning the variable. That is, if I am calling `new` to instantiate a new instance of the view, I should call `remove()` on the being discarded instance first... It seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In your example, you don't put the view's `el` into the DOM*, so nothing is referencing the view, then it will be collected by the garbage collection.

One good thing to ensure a view isn't bound to something anymore is to **call [`.remove()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on it**. It will remove:

- the view's `el` from the DOM,
- the jQuery DOM events
- the Backbone event listeners.

The Backbone [`.remove` source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/4a02b5fc3d9759ed8d3180b37cd982c8b30f8696/backbone.js#L1355-L1368):

> ```
> // Remove this view by taking the element out of the DOM, and removing any
> // applicable Backbone.Events listeners.
> remove: function() {
>     this._removeElement();
>     this.stopListening();
>     return this;
> },
>
> // Remove this view's element from the document and all event listeners
> // attached to it. Exposed for subclasses using an alternative DOM
> // manipulation API.
> _removeElement: function() {
>     this.$el.remove();
> },
> ```

As mentioned by [*mu is too short* in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595213/how-to-avoid-a-memory-leak-when-instantiating-child-views-in-backbone-js/41595430?noredirect=1#comment70395711_41595430) (and myself in almost every other answers), you should always [favor `listenTo` over `on` or `bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on) to avoid memory leaks and ease unbinding events.

When rendering child views, nested inside a parent view, a good practice is to keep an array of the child views to later call `.remove()` on each of them.

A simple list view might look like this:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Make an array available to keep all the child views
        this.childViews = [];
    },
    addOne: function(model) {
        var view = new Backbone.View({ model: model });

        // as you create new views, keep a reference into the array.
        this.childViews.push(view);

        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    },

    renderList: function() {
        // replace the view content completely with the template
        this.$el.html(this.templates());

        // then cleanup
        this.cleanup();

        // then render child views
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

        return this;
    },

    cleanup: function() {
        // quick way to call remove on all views of an array
        _.invoke(this.childViews, 'remove');
        // empty the array
        this.childViews = [];
    },
});
```

Though if other objects are listening to it, it won't be collected and may be a leak. It's important to keep track of the references and delete them all when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: This is also why you want to use `listenTo` rather than `on`, much easier to `stopListening` than to `off` everything.

Comment: Thanks. The _.invoke method is a neater way of doing it than my _.each loop.