# Want to send perticular value to javascript handler whenever clicked

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating multiple objects and binding to the same handler. My requirement is I want to send particular value to handle when it is called.

Code:

```
sliderObj = [];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    sliderObj[i] = this._turntableSlider = new SliderView();
    sliderObj[i].on("change:value", this._handleChangeSpeedSlider);
}
```

When handler is called for sliderObj[0] want to send value 0 similarly 1 for sliderObj[1] etc.

Please help me out how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried listenTo method it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
sliderObj[i].on("change:value", this._handleChangeSpeedSlider.bind(this, i));
```

[Simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/t46hsp3j/)

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to achieve what you want. The first parameter of `.bind` is the value for `this`. Every subsequent parameter does the following (as stated in the linked documentation): "Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function." So, in this example, `_handleChangeSpeedSlider` will receive the the following parameters (in order): `function _handleChangeSpeedSlider(i, model, options)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Prefer `listenTo` over `on`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16823746/1218980).

## Passing the index

Simplest solution would be to wrap the callback into an anonymous function.

But since we're looping and value of `i` will change, we need to create a simple function which returns a new function using the frozen value of `i`. (This is similar to using [TJ's `bind` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697229/1218980))

```
function getChangeSpeedHandler(index) {
    return function() {
        this._handleChangeSpeedSlider(index);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var slider = sliderObj[i] = new SliderView();
    this.listenTo(slider, "change:value", getChangeSpeedHandler(i));
}
```

## Passing the slider view

Assuming the value of `i` in the handler is only used to get the right `sliderObj`, you could pass the slider view directly.

```
function getChangeSpeedHandler(slider) {
    return function() {
        this._handleChangeSpeedSlider(slider);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var slider = sliderObj[i] = new SliderView();
    this.listenTo(slider, "change:value", getChangeSpeedHandler(slider));
}
```

## Delegating the event handling to the slider view

If you want to handle changes inside the `SliderView`, it should handle the event itself.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:value', this.onValueChange);
```

## Triggering custom events

If it's really the parent that needs to know the slider and their number is dynamic, you could pass the `i` value to the `SliderView` and then it could trigger a custom event.

In the slider view:

```
var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.index = options.index;
        // ...
    },
    onValueChange: function(model, value, options) {
        this.trigger('slider:change', value, this.index, this);
    },
});
```

Then in the parent:

```
initialize: function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var slider = sliderObj[i] = new SliderView({ index: i });
        this.listenTo(slider, "slider:change", this._handleChangeSpeedSlider);
    }
},
_handleChangeSpeedSlider: function(value, index, sliderView) {
    // handle the change
}
```