# Lost reference to this in TypeScript/Backbone situation

Tags: typescript, backbone.js

This is in a BackBone Model:

```
calculatePrice() {

}

initialize() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'caclulatePrice');
            this.on("change", function() {
                this.calculatePrice();    
            });
}
```

The problem is when this compiles the inner this is just this and not the _this which is actually the model.

Having looked around (and based on similar cases in CoffeeScript) it looks like the answer is something to do with => But I can't make this work e.g

```
this.on("change", function() => {
```

doesn't compile.

What do I need to do to make the inner this refer to the BackBone model (the class it is in)?

Update:

This works but it can't be the 'right' way.

```
let that = this;
this.on("change",  function() { that.caclulatePrice()  });
```

Comment: Tried this already `this.on("change", () => {...})`?

Comment: As said in mu's answer, use `listenTo` and `_.bindAll` becomes useless. [Avoid `this.on` as it's the old way of binding events and can leak memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on).

Comment: @SayanPal - er, no. It worked. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the desired `this` to the `calculatePrice` function:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'calculatePrice'); // I'm assuming that 'caclulatePrice' is a typo...
```

not the anonymous function you're handing to `this.on`.

A better way is to drop the `_.bindAll` and supply the desired `this` in the third argument to [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on):

```
this.on('change', this.calculatePrice, this);
```

Or, if you really want to use `_.bindAll`, just drop the anonymous function:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'calculatePrice');
this.on('change', this.calculatePrice);
```

You could also use [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) which will set the appropriate `this` for you.

Comment: this.on("change",  this.calculatePrice, this ); worked but bearing in mind @Emile Bergeron's comments I've gone with: this.listenTo(this, "change", this.calculatePrice)  ;  --- I thought that listenTo was only for other objects but it seems to work used like this. As you say _.bindAll was redundant in either case.

Comment: `a.listenTo(b, ev, f)` is pretty much `b.on(ev, f)` with some extra house keeping to keep track of `this` and what events are bound. You should be able to convert any `on` call to a `listenTo`.