# Passing context of view on event in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a context problem / design problem for my Backbone view.

## Goal

1. The user selects a user from a *list / user collection* in a separate view.
2. The mentioned view passes an global event that the `editUserView` receives (`"edit-contact"`).
3. The `editUserView` should receive this event and extract the (user) `model.id` attribute. By using this `model.id` I want to update the view with the corresponding object retrieved from the existing view model `Tsms.Collection.Users`.

## Problem

The context passed to the `updateView` function is wrong, and thus I do not have access to the parent views `.render()` function. The debugger states *"render() is not a function"*.

Since the context is not that of the parent view I am also unable to set the `this.current` variable.

How would I go about solving this problem?

### View code

```
Tsms.Views.editUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Tsms.Collections.Users,
    initialize: function(options) {
        Tsms.require_template('edituser')
        this.template = _.template($('#template_edituser').html());
        this.current = -1;

        Tsms.vent.on('edit-contact', this.updateView)
    },
    updateView: function(model) {
        this.current = model.id;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.get(this.current).attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone's `on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) actually takes three arguments:

> **on** `object.on(event, callback, [context])`
>   [...]
>
> To supply a **context** value for `this` when the callback is invoked, pass the optional last argument: `model.on('change', this.render, this)` or `model.on({change: this.render}, this)`.

The easiest and (currently) most idiomatic way to solve your problem would be to use the third `context` argument:

```
Tsms.vent.on('edit-contact', this.updateView, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

While [*mu is too short*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873197/1218980) is right, you should use Backbone's [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) to [avoid memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824080/1218980) (zombie views).

```
this.listenTo(Tsms.vent, 'edit-contact', this.updateView);
```

The context is automatically set to `this`, the calling view.

When [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) is called on the view, [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) is called and any references kept for events are removed.

Another reason to avoid `on` is that it should be the view that is responsible for the events it wants to handle, the event bus shouldn't have to know.